# how to skip index.php and method name in url of codeigniter 1.7.2?

Tags: php, codeigniter, version-control

I am newbie with Codeigniter 1.7.2. I want to skip index.php and method name of Site URL. But I don't know how to skip them.
My site url looks like -

```
http://localhost/mysadagi_voicetongues/index.php/deal_bazaar/PrivilegeDealsbazaar
```

So I want skip index.php and PrivilegeDealsbazaar from url.

Please give solution to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You want to remove index.php from URL only, right ?

Comment: @Mahendra , yes with function/method name also.

Comment: why are you using codeigniter 1.7?

Comment: @Mr. Kees Sonnema , sorry i can not change codeigniter version due to company policy reason.

Comment: @Suresh Kamrushi , how to Enable "rewrite_module" of apache.

Answer (score 0):

I forget to tell. open your config file: application/config/config.php and change this line

```
$config['index_page'] = “index.php”
```

To

```
$config['index_page'] = “”
```

Create a .htaccess file in the root of your app so

- system
- application
- assets
- .htaccess

To delete the index.php from your url use this .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^LoginTut.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|table-images|js|robots\.txt|css|captcha)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

It's not a very good idea to hide the controller name because you will get a lot of problems when routing and linking to other functions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: just create a file .htacces in your root. and paste the code in there. it should work.

Comment: see my edit. delete index.php from your config file. than it should work.

Comment: error occurs like-The requested URL /mysadagi_voicetongues/deal_bazaar/PrivilegeDealsbazaar was not found on this server by setting $config['index_page'] = '';.

Comment: what exactly is that? is that an url to your controller and method?

Comment: look at this http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html maybe it could help you.

Comment: look at the link i posted. that will help you :) and also. if my answer was helpful consider to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Use latest version on CI 2.1.3
You can use .htaccess to hide index.php from URL. You can use following .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
    #AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
    RewriteBase /projectforlder/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

You can not access your controller without specifying it in URL.

Comment: I can't use latest due to some company policy reason

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in 3 steps:

1) Create .htacess file in parallel to application holder
 and just copy past the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/       /* this will be your prj name. Change it as per your directory structure*/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

2) Change $config['index_page'] to blank in config.php in application folder as below:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

3) Enable "rewrite_module" of apache.

Comment: A error occurs like - The requested URL /mysadagi_voicetongues/deal_bazaar/PrivilegeDealsbazaar was not found on this server.

Comment: @user2265462: what environment you are using?

Comment: just restart your apache once you are done with all this things

Comment: just restart your wamp server than.

Comment: i am using same configuration, and it is working great. Just check two things 1) your base path "RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/" 2) rewrite_module should be on for apache.

Comment: now a Forbidden error occurs -You don't have permission to access /mysadagi_voicetongues/ /deal_bazaar/PrivilegeDealsbazaar on this server.

Comment: I think you have problem with Rewritebase Path only. Just play around it.